# Find unique and sort, does the latter only happen or is it by ECMA?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

```
var input = [1,1,2,3,10,5,3,4],
    stat = {},
    temp = [];

input.forEach(function(v) {
   stat[v] = 1;
});

for (v in stat) {
   temp.push(v);
}

console.log(temp); //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "10"]
```

How does the "sorting" occur?

**Edit:**
Made cross-browser screenshots (see comment) and a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/sortvsmyfind).

Comment: Seems to work "Cross-Browser" on new machines: http://browsershots.org/http://liebdich.biz/test/sort.html. Reported that IE screenshots are having a dialogue in front! IE11 works though. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "sorting" occurs in `for(v in stat)`. As per ECMA script standard, the order in which the keys are fetched is up to the vendor, and some browser vendors obviously chose to fetch all keys in sorted order. You shouldn't rely on this kind of "sorting" being "implemented in all browsers".

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference for the ECMA standard? Otherwise great answer. +1

Comment: Mind you, how could you distinguish whether the sorting happens on retrieval vs. insertion?

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, a reference for that wouldn't be bad either. ;-)

Comment: If I had found that reference, I would also have found the duplicate question on SO.

Comment: @dollarvar Surprisingly enough, it's in the [specification for the `for..in` statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4).

Comment: My point was more that the difference shouldn't practically matter. For performance reasons it could make more sense to do so on insertion – you'd shove all integer keys in some sort of ordered data structure, string keys in a hash table, and when iterating yield keys from both. One way to observe the difference might be to add a new key in the middle of iteration – assuming this is even allowed, in one case the new key shouldn't be reached since the iteration would work over a sorted copy of the keys, in the other case it would be reached if it's bigger than the other keys.

Comment: (That said, on Safari, it seems like iteration does indeed work over a copy of the keys when iteration starts. Of course this isn't conclusive since there might be other reasons to do that besides sorting.)

Comment: @millimoose In the ECMA script link, where does it say anything about the sorting?

Comment: @dollarvar You need to scroll down a bit. "The mechanics and **order** of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is **not specified**." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @millimoose Ah, looked for specific rule FOR sorting. ;-)

Comment: @millimoose Btw the first time that I read the A-literature. Sounds like Kant with all that serifs. ;-)

Comment: @dollarvar It's probably an artifact of how Javascript came to be. I.e. several subtly incompatible implementations that needed to converge on some common, compatible behaviour. This means that the spec will be involved, as well as highly formal, to accomodate the many historical warts, and make sure different browsers do the same thing for new features.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly not a rule:

```
var input = ["c", "b", "a"],
    stat = {},
    temp = [];

input.forEach(function(v) {
   stat[v] = 1;
});

for (v in stat) {
   temp.push(v);
}

console.log(temp); //["c", "b", "a"]
```

I'm guessing the sorting only happens for integer keys so that iterating over an object is consistent with iterating over an array. (Or that it's because objects and arrays are internally the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Items get pushed to the *temp* array in the order they are retrieved from the *stat* object, but you don't get to decide what order is that.

You can't sort key value pairs of js Objects at your will.

Comment: Ehmm, not an answer to my question. The `temp` IS sorted, ascending. How does that occur? As I try to pull the answer from your answer, you say, that the keys of objects are sorted ascending by default? Is that  all cross-browser, even ECMA convention?

Comment: the *stat* has an internal order, and to some extent it might look as  the keys get casted as string and ordered in ascending order. It's not consistent tho. I usually rely on third party tools like Underscore to perform sorting. http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: @amenadiel "it might look as the keys get casted as string and ordered in ascending order" – clearly not as per my answer. It doesn't make sense anyway, object keys are always strings in the first place. What seems to happen is that they get converted to integers, and the keys that do represent integers get special handling.