# Explain why Array.sort Act this way

Tags: javascript, arrays

when we try to sort an array of Numbers people say use this

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
   debugger;
   return (a > b) ? (1) : (-1);
});
debugger;
print(numbers);
```

if we watched the parameter a,b in the debugger mode we see the following

```
4,2
4,5
1,3
5,1
2,1
2,3
4,3
```

i need to know or an explanation of how sort function works from inside to give me these parameter ??? or i need some one explain whats happening ?

Comment: Why do you need this? The exact sequence of comparator calls is unimportant and unreliable.

Comment: Personally, I consider this one of the things where I DGAF how it works XD

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol dont you if you need to if the sort function is incompatible with all browsers ;) you will need to know the prototype to make it to.

Comment: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/merge-sort

Comment: @Marwan Erm... .`sort` works in all browsers, and takes a callback which is given `a` and `b` and must return a value depending on how the values compare. That's it.

Comment: @developerCK nice one too :) thanks guys

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: on top of that, the behaviour of [`Array#sort`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) is **implementation-defined** (read: unportable and unreliable) unless the sort function exhibits *reflexivity*, *symmetry* and *transitivity*, which the OP's function does not.

Comment: On addition to @NiettheDarkAbsol, the callback appears to be called with parameters in random order, but in fact it's part of the algorithm used for the sort function. The return value of the callback tells the algorithm where the element needs to be placed. -1 = a before b, 1 = b before a, atleast in this case. The bigger the array the more the algorithm needs to query certain elements.

Comment: And one more resource that helped me understand what is actually happening (I'm more a visual guy really) http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/Gifs/mergeSort.gif

Comment: Just to put it in, I found a new way for *[find unique and sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405567/find-unique-and-sort-does-the-latter-only-happen-or-is-it-rule)*, but it is [sloooow](http://jsperf.com/sortvsmyfind). :(

Comment: because its a merge sort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I use this :

```
var num = [4,2,5,1,3];
num.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

Comment: its almost the same you just added a case that the result can be zero and in that case no sort will happen and thats not an answer for my question

Comment: But it's nicer... :) Ok here's the WebKit's way to do it, if you really care. But there is probably no good reason to study the native code apart from mere curiosity. https://gist.github.com/Pewpewarrows/964673